# android app crashes /lages on some phones

Tags: android

```
public class drawer extends implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    NavigationView navigationView=null;
    Toolbar toolbar=null;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Main_fragment fragment= new Main_fragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.app_bar_search) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.Home) {
            Main_fragment fragment= new Main_fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.Timetable) {
            timtable fragment= new timtable();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.Create_Class) {
            CreateClass fragment= new CreateClass();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.Attendance) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Messenger) {

        } else if (id == R.id.change) {
            change_email_pass fragment= new change_email_pass();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.Sign_out) {
            auth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent=new Intent(drawer.this,signin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.malik.faroo.aninterface"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies 
{
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

}
```

Comment: Show the logcat for crashes.

Comment: always post the log errors please